# Read by key and parse as JSON

Tags: javascript, json

If I have the following JSON array:

```
[
    {"data":
        [
            {"W":1,"A1":"123"},
            {"W":1,"A1":"456"},
            {"W":2,"A1":"4578"},
            {"W":2,"A1":"2423"},
            {"W":2,"A1":"2432"},
            {"W":2,"A1":"24324"}
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I convert it to:

```
[
    {"1":[
        {"A1":"123"},
        {"A1":"456"}
    ]},
    {"2":[
        {"A1":"4578"},
        {"A1":"2423"},
        {"A1":"2432"},
        {"A1":"24324"}
    ]}
]
```

Comment: what do you want to access??

Comment: Group by W all the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in native Javascript, and by following the **functional way** which tends to be more sexy, shorter. To handle this, you can simulate an **hashmap** key/value.

You can use [**Array.prototype.reduce()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [**Array.prototype.concat()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) which are powerful method.

```
      //Concat reduce result to an array
  //We initialize our result process with an empty object
  var filter = [].concat.apply(array[0].data.reduce(function(hash, current){
      //If my hashmap get current.W as key
      return hash.hasOwnProperty(current.W)
      //push our current object to our map, and return the hashmap
      ? (hash[current.W].push({'A1': current.A1}), hash)
      //otherwise, create an hashmap key with an array as value, and return the hashmap
      : (hash[current.W] = [{'A1': current.A1}], hash);
  }, {}));

  console.log(filter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy):

> #### groupBy_.groupBy(list, iteratee, [context])
>
> Splits a collection into sets, grouped by the result of running each value through iteratee. If iteratee is a string instead of a function, groups by the property named by iteratee on each of the values.

```
_.groupBy([1.3, 2.1, 2.4], function(num){ return Math.floor(num); });
=> {1: [1.3], 2: [2.1, 2.4]}

_.groupBy(['one', 'two', 'three'], 'length');
=> {3: ["one", "two"], 5: ["three"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically do some reducing:

```js
var obj = [{
        "data": [
            { "W": 1, "A1": "123" },
            { "W": 1, "A1": "456" },
            { "W": 2, "A1": "4578" },
            { "W": 2, "A1": "2423" },
            { "W": 2, "A1": "2432" },
            { "W": 2, "A1": "24324" }
        ]
    }],
    grouped = obj[0].data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.W] = r[a.W] || [];
        r[a.W].push({ A1: a.A1 });
        return r;
    }, {}),
    groupedAsDesired = Object.keys(grouped).reduce(function (r, a) {
        var o = {};
        o[a] = grouped[a];
        r.push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>grouped: ' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>groupedAsDesired: ' + JSON.stringify(groupedAsDesired, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

A small hint, it is not necessary to wrap objects with different properties in arrays, like your wanted result. Have a look for the difference in the results window: `grouped` vs `groupedAsDesired`.